# Cannot create new Nest project using yarn as a package manager

Tags: nestjs, yarnpkg

I couldn't create a new NestJS project when doing `nest new project-name` using yarn as a package manager. However, whenever I chooses npm, it successfully create the directories.

My nest version is 8.1.1.

My yarn version is 1.22.11.

My npm version is 6.14.1.

My node version is 14.0.0.

I am using Windows 10 git bash mintty

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what error you are getting as well. I haven't seen a problem using yarn when creating a Nest application

Comment: I have the same issue. Notice me if you find out how to solve this.